# How to access Redux store from another component and pass its data to out of redux context?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a React app with three components A, B, and C. In component A, I have a button to submit. In component B, I have wrapped the Redux store, and in component C, I have a form. I cannot change this structure as it is an existing format. Every time I make changes to the form, the store inside B gets updated.

COMP A - buttons here
COMP B - redux store here
COMP C - form

Now, I want to share the information in B's store with component A when I click the button. I need to make an API call with the information in B's store. How can I access B's store from component A and pass its data to the API call?

Comment: What problem do you have in putting the 3 components inside the Redux context?

Comment: What is preventing component A from subscribing to the redux store? Please [edit] to clarify the issue and to include some relevant [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping all 3 components in some new **context provider** and initialize a shared state.

In component B, when redux state changes , trigger useEffect hook and update shared context state.

Back in component A, capture shared context state change through useEffect hook.

sample working shown here [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-sea-reflik?file=/src/components/ComponentB.js)

Comment: Redux is already a shared state, duplicating state would be anti-pattern.